# Bijection between finite and infinite sequences over Reals.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, set-theory, cardinals

So define the set of finite sequences to be $S={a_1,a_2,\cdots}$ where $a_k$ are in real numbers and only finitely many of them are non-zero. The set of infinite sequences is defined similarly except that we can have infinitely many non-zero terms. How do I prove that there does not exist a bijection between these two sets?

Comment: As you tagged this as *linear algebra*, could it be that instead of bijection you mean isomorphism of real vector spaces?

Comment: I was wondering how I show that the set of infinite sequences with entries in R is uncountably infinite-
dimensional as a vector space over R.

Comment: @JohnvonNeumann Isn't the set of infinite sequences of real numbers manifestly a *countably* infinite-dimensional vector space over R?

Comment: spaceisdarkgreen : not so manifestly though

Answer (score 2):

You don't, because there exist such bijections. The first one is (essentially) $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}^n$, which has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, and the second one is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, which also has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.